# Reload <body> with jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, reload

I have an index.php that updates every second user sessions:

[Index.php (before )]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function($) {
    var refresh = setInterval(function() {
        $.post('myfolder/reload_info.post.php', {
            id: <?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>
        }, function(data){
            clearInterval(this);
        });
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

[reload_info.post.php]

```
(sql query... // $row is the result)
$_SESSION['name'] = $row->name;
$_SESSION['mail'] = $row->mail;
$_SESSION['status'] = $row->stat;
$_SESSION['cf'] = $row->cf;
```

All functions of the site using any session are usually charged if there is any change in the database (MySQL). What I would like is to update the body of index.php () without reloading the page.

That is, if I open the index.php file and have nothing between the   and editing the file I put any text after this a second, carrying the text without having to press F5 or take a location.reload ().

Is it possible? Thank you. :)

Comment: What's the point in reloading the entire body?  Why not just the parts you need to change?  I guess I don't see the benefit in not reloading the page at this point.

Comment: Inside the <body> I just have to `div.container` and nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are after something like joconut: https://github.com/vdemedes/joconut

Answer (score 0):

you want something like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function($) {
var id="<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>";
    var refresh = setInterval(function() {
        $.post('myfolder/reload_info.post.php', {
            id: id;
        }, function(data){
            clearInterval(this);
            $('body .container').html(data);
        });
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

in reload_info.post.php you should return something...

echo echo $_SESSION['id'];

Comment: replace() is a really function?!

Comment: No, that disappeared with all content (text only lorem ipsum) and didn't return anything...

Comment: will update, as i understand, but mixig the php and js is bad idea

Comment: Hm, I understood. Well, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Yeah! That's really what I want.